# Facebook Graph Query Search Stream for Link

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can anyone tell me if its possible to search public facebook streams for specific URLs? And if yes, what is the FQL and do I need to set access token?

**Update:** What about using graph api.... or even searching the link table? I tried using the graph api to search the stream table, but its not bring back great results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search nearly anything in FQL using the [undocumented CONTAINS() function](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12630401/documentation-for-contains-in-fql):

```
SELECT actor_id, created_time, message, attachment FROM stream WHERE CONTAINS('stackoverflow.com`)
```

You need to be careful using it, because the results will be filtered *after* the query runs to only show items that are visible to the current session user. You may get empty data sets returned even though there are lots of items that meet your criteria. AFAIK, there is no `visible_to_me` field where you can filter the posts prior to the FB visibility filter.

You always need an access token to use the `stream` table.

Comment: Does the graph api search work better? Would that be a better alternative, though I do see that graph search is not returning things I want either. https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook&type=post

Comment: Search within Facebook is a strange thing. I can't say either of them works "better". They both give odd results in different ways.